# Is there a way to make Java Applets work on the latest version of Google Chrome?

Tags: java, google-chrome, npapi

Are there any addons or extensions that allow you to run java on the latest version of google chrome? Are there any ways of making this possible?

Comment: No. Java applets are a dead technology; you need to stop using them.

Comment: It's not my decision, I must use them

Comment: "If you have problems accessing Java applications using Chrome, Oracle recommends using Internet Explorer (Windows) or Safari (Mac OS X) instead." - 
down vote
In short no. See this post from Sun

https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml

Comment: I am required to allow users to access this java applet in Chrome, unfortunately Lionel

Comment: @BarneyChambers That choice is no longer yours to make, Chrome is actively blocking the applet plugin in there doesn't seem to be any chance in the future that that decision will change.  You need to go back to who ever is making these decisions and let them know that they will need to discus the issue with Google directly or change there approach - that's the long answer - *"If you have problems accessing Java applications using Chrome, Oracle recommends using Internet Explorer (Windows) or Safari (Mac OS X) instead."*

Comment: @BarneyChambers Then you need to talk to whoever has set those requirements, because they are impossible to fulfill.

Comment: Not impossible, just found a webapplet called IETab that makes it work. Never say Never!

Answer (score 0):

In short no. See this post from Oracle

https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml

Comment: What about "In long"? ;) I don't mind messing around a bit if needed

Comment: Can you elaborate to what "In long" might be?

Comment: You said "In short there's no way".. Is there any "long way round" to get it to work, alternatively?

Comment: Give this a try: http://knowledge.kaltura.com/enabling-silverlight-plugin-npapi-plugins-chrome

Comment: @BarneyChambers _In short no. [In Long,] See this post from Oracle[...]_